# Phone turns off at random

Tags: battery, power-on

I have a note 1 N7000, and each time the screen began flickering and after that it shut down. This got worse after flashing a cyanogenmod rom. By plugging in the charger the battery seemed empty, but wasn't. After a while the battery indicator used to show charged 70 % or more. Put the charger cable off and the situation repeated after a short time of usage.

Last night it started turning off at boot and wouldn't turn on unless on charge. I flashed a original JB rom since the problem doesn't happen when on recovery/download mode. but now it does it even when connected on charge.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It sounds like a hardware fault if it happens on different firmwares to be honest. Can you try a new battery? You'll probably need to go to a service centre with the device. Have you calibrated the battery at all?

Comment: Fixed the problem with a new battery! :)

Comment: Brilliant, that's an easy fix at least! :) Glad to hear it.